# querying a Database while updating Database table at regular time interval

Tags: python, database, flask

I have a question that might be simple but I don't really know where to look and googling it didn't give me any result.
This is what I would like to achieve and I would like to know if there is any problem with the design or if there are better ways to do it:

1. I have Database with a table that updates every 30 seconds by calling the Bloomberg API functions in Python and downloading the last price for a list of securities
2. I have a flask web app with a page that queries this Database say also every 30 seconds or every 1 minute (it's not very important) and then displays a table with the values in it (so the table is live updating)

Process 1 is independent of process 2.

My question is what happens if the query is sent at the same time as the Database is updating?
Is it something I should be concerned about?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the transaction isolation level used by the database driver in process 2.  Some isolation levels allow reading uncommitted changes, some do not - your database's documentation should describe the available levels.

Comment: Is there any reason for not showing the data directly before it arrives in the database?

Comment: @Philip my thinking is that if I show the data directly then the first time the user loads the page it will take a while until the data are downloaded from bloomberg server. If I save the Data to the DB then every time someone loads the page the data are already in the DB because I put in place a separate process that handles the data download. Also I will need to save the data so i think it makes sense to save into DB first and then read from it

Comment: @gioxc88. The answer to your question will really depend on the underlying database I think - not all databases handles this the same way. However, if your are using a db for timeseries I'm quite sure that you will be home safe. The same goes for SQL Server as far as I know. These will all be able to handle parallel query actions.